# How to reduce screen saturation on android 6 without root?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a galaxy j7.
Have any way to reduce screen saturation of this phone?

I saw in google some clues about a Screen Adjuster... but i didnt found it in Google Play.
So i tried a bunch of apps, but none of these have the option to reduce satiration. Only increase of brightness and color.

I have found the monocromacy mode. But i would like a little of saturation, not much, but a little.